# Laravel, PHP: json_encode gives different result in Laravel and raw PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-4

In my **mysql** database table there are utf-8 characters.(my table collation is **utf8_unicode_ci**)

```
à¦…à§à¦¯à¦¾à¦¸à¦¿à¦¡à¦¿à¦¤à¦¿ à¦•à¦®à¦¿à§Ÿà§‡ à¦‰à¦°à§à¦¬à¦°à¦¤à¦¾ à¦«à¦¿à¦°à¦¿à§Ÿà§‡ à¦†à¦¨à¦¤à§‡ à¦•à§‹à¦¨à¦Ÿà¦¿ à¦¬à§à¦¯à¦¬à¦¹à¦¾à¦° à¦•à¦°à¦¾ à¦¹à§Ÿ?
```

Now when i get the table column using **Laravel Model** and the **json_encode** the data, i get

```
"\u00e0\u00a6\u2026\u00e0\u00a7\u008d\u00e0\u00a6\u00af\u00e0\u00a6\u00be\u00e0\u00a6\u00b8\u00e0\u00a6\u00bf\u00e0\u00a6\u00a1\u00e0\u00a6\u00bf\u00e0\u00a6\u00a4\u00e0\u00a6\u00bf \u00e0\u00a6\u2022\u00e0\u00a6\u00ae\u00e0\u00a6\u00bf\u00e0\u00a7\u0178\u00e0\u00a7\u2021 \u00e0\u00a6\u2030\u00e0\u00a6\u00b0\u00e0\u00a7\u008d\u00e0\u00a6\u00ac\u00e0\u00a6\u00b0\u00e0\u00a6\u00a4\u00e0\u00a6\u00be \u00e0\u00a6\u00ab\u00e0\u00a6\u00bf\u00e0\u00a6\u00b0\u00e0\u00a6\u00bf\u00e0\u00a7\u0178\u00e0\u00a7\u2021 \u00e0\u00a6\u2020\u00e0\u00a6\u00a8\u00e0\u00a6\u00a4\u00e0\u00a7\u2021 \u00e0\u00a6\u2022\u00e0\u00a7\u2039\u00e0\u00a6\u00a8\u00e0\u00a6\u0178\u00e0\u00a6\u00bf \u00e0\u00a6\u00ac\u00e0\u00a7\u008d\u00e0\u00a6\u00af\u00e0\u00a6\u00ac\u00e0\u00a6\u00b9\u00e0\u00a6\u00be\u00e0\u00a6\u00b0 \u00e0\u00a6\u2022\u00e0\u00a6\u00b0\u00e0\u00a6\u00be \u00e0\u00a6\u00b9\u00e0\u00a7\u0178? "
```

But if i fetch the column using **mysqli prepared statement in plain PHP** and the use **json_encode**, i get

```
"\u0985\u09cd\u09af\u09be\u09b8\u09bf\u09a1\u09bf\u09a4\u09bf \u0995\u09ae\u09bf\u09df\u09c7 \u0989\u09b0\u09cd\u09ac\u09b0\u09a4\u09be \u09ab\u09bf\u09b0\u09bf\u09df\u09c7 \u0986\u09a8\u09a4\u09c7 \u0995\u09cb\u09a8\u099f\u09bf \u09ac\u09cd\u09af\u09ac\u09b9\u09be\u09b0 \u0995\u09b0\u09be \u09b9\u09df? "
```

I want this json, but laravel generating another one.

**Laravel code:**

```
app/config/database.php
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',  

//Model
class Problem extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'problems';

}
// Controller function
public function test()
{
    $tmp = Problem::find(33551);
    return json_encode($tmp['body']);
}
```

**Plain PHP code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT body FROM problems WHERE id = ?";
$id = 33551;
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("i", $id);
$statement->execute();
$ret = "";
$statement->bind_result($ret);
$statement->fetch();
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Why is json_encode working so strangely in laravel. How can i solve this problem ?
I'm using Laravel 4.2
Please help...

Comment: I think you should first try to get the result properly encoded.. Upgrade to php 5.4 if you have a previous version and use  json_encode( $ret, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ); to get the UTF8 encoded json

Comment: i'm using PHP 5.5 , and JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE gives "à¦…à§à¦¯à¦¾à¦¸à.........", but i want "\u0985\u09cd\u09af\u09be........"

Comment: is it normal to get "à¦…à§à¦¯à¦¾à¦¸à........."? Maybe there is something wrong with your data? I give focus on that because you will not be able to solve the problem of validating your data if they are wrong in the first place.. if you run the query in mysql terminal or phpmyadmin do you get the results properly encoded?  if not check if the body column has also utf8_unicode_ci collation and try to reinsert the data

Comment: all my table columns have utf8_unicode_ci collation and my data is not invalid because when i show the "à¦…à§à¦¯à¦¾à¦¸à........." in html page it converts to Bangla language correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference with json_encode,you should check the result you got from the both way,

and `Problem::find(33551)` will not get column "body",it will get whole row(an object) with id 33551..

you should try var_dump($tmp) and see what you have got.

get column body using `$tmp->body`

Comment: i used $tmp['body'] to get column body.That's same as $tmp->body, right ?

Comment: Eloquent Models implement the `ArrayAccess` interface, so there should be no difference

Comment: @palatok,Cash2m..ok then,i don't remember,no influence about this question.